# Get single database row with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, row, opencart

This sounds daft and easy but I'm not 100% sure here.

I have this code:

```
$query = $this->db->query("MY QUERY");
```

The query will result in one row and I basically want to get the column called "id" from that single row so I can echo something like $query->db->row->id..

How do I do this?

Comment: It depends on what database layer you're using - MySQLi? PDO?

Comment: What object is `db`? PDO? MySQLi? Custom?

Comment: I am using OpenCarts database method

Comment: What does print_r($query) look like?

Comment: ( [row] => Array ( [email_id] => 1467))

Comment: You do realise that OpenCart has features to call strings and variables from the database without SQL commands.

Comment: The actual correct answer is `echo $query->row['id'];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any details, here is a wild guess

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 1,1')
$results = $query->rows();
//if rows() returns an object
$id = $results->email_id;

//if that rows() functions returns ( [row] => Array ( [email_id] => 1467)) 
$id = $results['row']['email_id'];
```

Comment: I think the OP was more concerned with the PHP code to fetch the value from the `id` column into a variable (which is of course dependent upon the underlying database layer).

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was a littlew unclear. How do I then echo that variable. I tried things like echo $query->db->row('id') or $query->db->row->id and that didn't do anything. Thanks

Comment: I edited the question to reflect `opencart` syntax

Comment: I found the problem, the array should have been $results[0]['email_id']  thanks for your help phil :)